# UIPickerView selected item's frame

Tags: ios, uipickerview

Is there a way to get the frame of the currently selected UIPickerView's item?

I tried the following (as suggested below) but I always get a nil back:

```
-(void) pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView 
      didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row 
       inComponent:(NSInteger)component{


    UIView *selected = [pickerView viewForRow:row forComponent:component];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
UIView *view=[picker viewForRow:[picker selectedRowInComponent:1] forComponent:1];


CGRect viewframe=[view frame];
```

Comment: I always get a nil back from viewForRow:forComponent:  I call it within pickerView:didSelectRow:inComponent:  Any ideas? O:-)

Comment: - (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view here u have to return the view then only u can retrieve them later

Comment: implement above delegate method